# Azure Data Factory Row Counts

Tags: azure-data-factory

Has anyone noticed the rows counts between a Copy Pipeline execution between Debug mode and Trigger mode are different?

I have a few copy pipelines that when I execute in Debug mode I get a different row count (can be significant) than I do when in Trigger mode. I have validated the count on the source has not changed between the 2 runs. I would expect that the number of rows copied would be the same for each type of run.

Comment: Can you please provide a sample of your data, your source, and sink types to be able to repro?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to copy sample data in my lab environment using copy data pipeline and did not notice any difference in counts when running using Debug mode and using Trigger mode.

Please double-check the data you are copying from source to sink while running in both debug and trigger mode.

If you still seeing discrepancies, please raise a support ticket for the support engineer to investigate.